# Using getcompletion function for insert mode autocompletion

Tags: autocompletion, insert-mode

I recently became aware of the `getcompletion` function which can return autocompletion options for a variety of different things *(shell commands, vim autocommand events, files, etc.)*.  Many of the types of things that it can autocomplete are not available in insert mode completion *(see `ins-completion`)*.  Is there a way of harnessing `getcompletion` in insert mode autocompletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up "user completion" (invoked with in insert mode with <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd>) to do this:

```
function! CompleteColorschemes(findstart, base)
  if a:findstart
    " locate the start of the word
    let line = getline('.')
    let start = col('.') - 1
    while start > 0 && line[start - 1] =~ '\a'
      let start -= 1
    endwhile
    return start
  else
    " Use getcompletion() to complete colorschemes
    return getcompletion(a:base, 'color')
  endif
endfunction
set completefunc=CompleteColorschemes
```

This is a slight adaptation of the example given in `:help complete-functions`.

Omni completion (`omnifunc`, <kbd>Ctrl-X</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd>) works in the same way, and is intended for filetype-specific completions